# How can I use COUNT and DISTINCT in MYSQL to create a separate count for each distinct value?

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I have a list of cities and counties in MYSQL that each represent a unique datapoint. I want to run a query that will count how many times each different county appears. For example:

```
city            state       county
chantilly       virginia     fairfax
chantilly       virginia     fairfax
reston          virginia     fairfax
leesburg        virginia     loudon
ashburn         virginia     loudon
manassas        virginia     prince william
```

should result in:

```
county        count
fairfax          3
loudon           2
prince william   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select county, count(county) as Count from table group by county;
```